# Connected components of large induced subgraphs of hypercubes

Tags: extremal-graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $H$ be the $n$-dimensional hypercube, i.e. $\{0,1\}^n$ with edges between two vertices if and only if they differ in exactly one co-ordinate. We say that an edge is in direction $i$ if its endpoints differ in exactly the $i$'th co-ordinate. Suppose $V$ is a subset of $H$ such that $|V| > 2^{n-1}$. Is it true that at least one connected component of the graph induced by $V$ contains edges in all $n$ direction?

Comment: Is it known how many connected components there can be for such a subgraph?  For small n, the answer seems to be 1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.08 

Comment: Gerhard, one can have two components in $\{0,1\}^4$ already.

Comment: Indeed Gjergji, also for n=3.  I wasn't thinking hard enough when I made the earlier comment.  Taking V to be the set of all points with an even number of bits gives the maximum number of connected components; adding 1 more point connects at most n of those components.  I originally thought there was a simpler argument to provide a yes answer.  I now feel that something like Hall's theorem is needed, after remembering about the V above.  Gerhard "Coffee Does Make A Difference" Paseman, 2011.08.08

Comment: We can verify this by hand for n=4. We can break up the proof into 2-3 cases. Consider the two subcubes given by $x_1 = 0$ and $x_1 =1$. One of the two subcubes must contain at least 5 of the 9 points. If these form a connected component then we are done since at least one of these points connects to a point in the other subcube. There is only one case (up to isomorphism) when these points don't form a connected graph. In that case also it is easy to argue that the conjecture holds. 

Please let me know if something looks wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified the case $n=4$ (using a computer or elsewise)?

Comment: Unless I was wrong, I verified the conjecture for n=5 (by hand).

Comment: I wonder, can we at least proof that there is a component that contains edges in at least 2 directions? (I.e. one that is not just a vertex or an edge.)

Comment: @domortop: Yes, we can. We get $2^{n-2}$ subcubes of size 4 by fixing the first $n-2$ co-ordinates of $H$. Since $|V| > 2^{n-1}$ at least one of these subcubes has 3 points in it. This implies 2 directions. Since we have proof by hand for $n$ up to 5, we can conclude that some component will have 5 directions. 

Comment: Of course, nice!

Comment: And how about the (much) weaker assertion that there exists a connected component of size at least $n+1$? (Cf. the case where $V$ consists of all even-weight vertices and just one odd-weight vertex.)

Comment: Good question Seva. Not sure how to prove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Thanks to Sukhada Fadnavis and Seva for pointing out in the comments that the argument I had written here was wrong. Instead I will point you to the paper where this is proved

> ["Bulky subgraphs of the hypercube"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669899903621), by Andrei Kotlov, Europ. J. Combinatorics (2000) **21**, 503-507

As far as I can tell from looking at the literature, it is not known if there are configurations of more than $2^{n-1}$ vertices for which one can not find $n+1$ of them which induce a tree with an edge in every direction. This would be a strengthening of the result in question.

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution. I suppose, your $d$ is actually the degree if $u$ in the bipartite subgraph, induced by $X$ and $N_G(X)$ (*not* in $G$), and $N(G)$ was meant to be $N_G(X)$; is this correct? Now, could you explain the conclusion that "the degree of a vertex in $N_G(X)$ is always less than or equal to the degree of its neighbours in $X$"? And, finally, exactly where you use the assumption that none of the connected components has an edge in every direction? Thanks! 

Comment: Hi Gjergji, using your notation above, if $x_1, x_2$ are in the same connected component then I don't see why the fourth vertex $v$ should be in $N_G(X)$. Could you please explain? Thanks.  

Comment: @Sukhada: this is actually easy: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both neighbors of $u$, then each of hem differs from $u$ in just one coordinate, and the fourth vertex, say $v$, differs from $u$ in both these coordinates, and differs from each of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in exactly one coordinate; hence $v$ is a neighbor both of $x_1$ and $x_2$. 

Comment: @ Seva. But $v$ may be in $V$, then the edges between $x_1, x_2$ and $v$ don't show up in the induced bipartite graph between $V$ and $H\V$. 

Comment: @Sukhada: I agree, this is a rather ambiguous point.

Comment: @Gjeirgji

I think there are examples for $n=3$ where it is not true that the degree of a vertex in $N_G(V)$ is less than or equal to the degree of of it's neighbors in $V$ (where we consider the bipartite graph induced by $V$ and $H\V$). 

Consider $n=3$ and $V = \\{(000), (010), (011), (101)\\}$. None of the connected components of $V$ contain edges in all directions but the number of neighbors of (001) in $V$ is greater than the number of neighbors of $(000)$ and $(011)$ in $H\V$. 

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the answer Gjeirgji :)